# How do I make pelican include content/some_dir without inspecting it for pages?

Tags: python, pelican

`content/some_dir` contains subdirectories that should not be scanned for pages or templates and .html files and images that should be presented as is.  Including `some_dir` in `STATIC_PATHS` and `PAGE_EXCLUDES` doesn't seem to stop pelican from scanning through and warning me that my pages are formatted incorrectly, images don't have `alt`'s, etc.

Answer (score 3):

In my pelican site I have a LOT of pre-formatted static html that I didn't want to have to edit. (Static archive of old web forums - 30K html files)

You can use STATIC_PATHS, with ARTICLE_EXCLUDES and PAGE_EXCLUDES to do what you want, but you'll discover that for some reason pelican still wants to look at each file. Doing this increased my build times 10x or so with my data.  In short, use the static_paths to add your html files, and then the excludes settings to tell pelican to not process them.

Instead I tried the following, and use this now.  In my top-level directory, I made a directory 'output-skel' and then I edited my Makefile.  In the html target, I added this line as one of the commands that is run:

```
        rsync -SHqav output-skel/ $(OUTPUTDIR)
```

so my html make block looks like this:

```
html:
    $(PELICAN) $(INPUTDIR) -o $(OUTPUTDIR) -s $(CONFFILE) $(PELICANOPTS)
    rsync -SHqav output-skel/ $(OUTPUTDIR)
```

This way, I can put ANY file I want to include in my output in it's relative path in output-skel and have it show up where I want it.

This sure beats having 30k entries in my STATIC_PATHS.  I put .htaccess files, static-html, some 'downloads' files there.

As an aside, I also add the following lines to my html make target:

```
        chown -R root:www $(OUTPUTDIR)
        find $(OUTPUTDIR) -type d | xargs chmod 750
        find $(OUTPUTDIR) -type f | xargs chmod 640
```

Just to keep things neat and tidy.

Answer (score 2):

You could try `ARTICLE_EXCLUDES` (list of directories to exclude when looking for articles) or `IGNORE_FILES` (list of file globbing patterns to match against the source files to be ignored by the processor).

Source : http://docs.getpelican.com/en/3.3.0/settings.html